Alien invasion movie with sores and blob
I saw a 50s or 60s movie when I was a kid that I have been trying to identify and see again for about 30 years. These rocks fall to earth, and if you pick one up - it gives off a gas, you get a large sore and it takes over your body.  At the end, there is this large facility where the aliens are growing a blob and it escapes and moves cross country.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

You probably saw Quatermass II, (1957), Hammer Films' big-screen remake of a BBC serial of the same name from 1955.  The following synopsis is actually from the TV serial:

Several years after the previous serial took place, Professor
  Quatermass is trying to perfect a dangerously unstable nuclear-powered
  rocket engine. After a disastrous test firing in Australia, his future
  son-in-law, Captain John Dillon, draws the Professor's attention to a
  strange hollow meteorite which interrupted an Army Training exercise. Quatermass and Dillon investigate, and discover a vast
  government production plant which has some connection with the
  meteorites. After coming in contact with the noxious gas contained
  inside the meteorites, Dillon is taken away by the plant's security
  guards. When Quatermass presses this issue with an old civil service
  acquaintance, he learns that the plant is supposedly making synthetic
  food. Both men learn that this is untrue, and that the true products
  of the plant will threaten the world itself.

The "true products of the plant" are the "blobs".  I remember the possessed scientists are trying to acclimate the blobs to Earth's atmosphere.
